# Can CNN reduce input size by a specified ratio

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a fully convoluted CNN and I have no problem designing it to have an exact same output size by using "same" padding and a stride of one.

However, I have an image-translation problem where I need the output being resized to `(W/26, H/15)` where `(W, H)` is the size of the input. (Resizing the image beforehand is problematic, it won't be an option in our case)

I understand by using the formula: `O = (I - F +2P )/s + 1`. Where:

- `O`: output size
- `I`: input size
- `F`: filter size
- `P`: padding
- `s`: stride

I may be able to use some really strange filter size to achieve this. But is there a systematic or organized way to construct such a network to reduce input size?

Answer (score 0):

Getting that precise output size playing only with filter size and stride is going to give you some headaches.

My two cents: whenever the size of your output is particularly weird (like `(w//26, h//15)`), interpolation layers might be helpful to get you to that particular size.

For example:

- PyTorch you can use [`torch.nn.functional.interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate).
- Tensorflow [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize)